# MySQL query to calculate percentage by month by year with subquery who depends on outer query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```sql
SELECT tk.naziv tip, 
       MONTH(ia.created_at) month_number, 
       MONTHNAME(ia.created_at) AS x, 
       COUNT(sia.id) as y,           
       COUNT(sia.id) / ( SELECT COUNT(x.id) 
                         FROM stavke x 
                         WHERE YEAR(x.created_at) = YEAR(NOW()) 
                           AND MONTH(x.created_at) = MONTH(ia.created_at))
FROM stavke sia,
     izvjestaji ia,
     komitenti k,
     tipovi tk
WHERE YEAR(ia.created_at) = YEAR(NOW())
  AND   ia.komitent_id = k.id
  AND   sia.izvjestaj_id = ia.id
  AND   k.tip_komitenta_id = tk.id
GROUP BY tk.naziv, 
         MONTH(ia.created_at), 
         MONTHNAME(ia.created_at)    
ORDER BY MONTH(ia.created_at) ASC;
```

which fails with the following error:

> [42000][1055] Expression #5 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'mydb.ia.created_at' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

I do not want to disable sql_mode=only_full_group_by.

Trying to get the count and percentage of child table, but per month and year, in order to compare by tip.

Example:

```
izvjestaji table
id tip created_at
1  1   Date in January
2  2   Date in January
3  1   Date in February

stavke table
id izvjestaj_id created_at
1  1            Date in January
2  2            Date in February

Result
tip month_number x        y percent
1   1            January  1 0.5
2   1            January  1 0.5
1   2            February 2 1
```

Thank you!

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Server tells about the subquery - it is not a part of GROUP BY expression really.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the fields to the `GROUP BY`as follows:

```
SELECT tk.naziv tip, 
       MONTH(ia.created_at) month_number, 
       MONTHNAME(ia.created_at) AS x, 
       COUNT(sia.id) as y,           
       COUNT(sia.id) / ( SELECT COUNT(x.id) 
                         FROM stavke x 
                         WHERE YEAR(x.created_at) = YEAR(NOW()) 
                           AND MONTH(x.created_at) = MONTH(ia.created_at))
FROM stavke sia,
     izvjestaji ia,
     komitenti k,
     tipovi tk
WHERE YEAR(ia.created_at) = YEAR(NOW())
  AND   ia.komitent_id = k.id
  AND   sia.izvjestaj_id = ia.id
  AND   k.tip_komitenta_id = tk.id
GROUP BY tk.naziv, 
         MONTH(ia.created_at), 
         MONTHNAME(ia.created_at),
         YEAR(x.created_at),     /*++++++++++++++++ ADDED ++++++++++++++++*/
         MONTH(x.created_at)     /*++++++++++++++++ ADDED ++++++++++++++++*/
ORDER BY MONTH(ia.created_at) ASC;
```